# Flex Mobile 4.6 Unicode Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, unicode, character

I am building an application for android using flash builder 4.6. I am trying to display unicode character as in this xml "http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/index.xml"

Characters are displayed correctly when run on simulator provided by flash builder but when installed on android, it displays square boxes [][][][][][][][][]. How can i go about resolving this issue so that font embeds correctly?

Version of android I tested on was 2.3.5. My code is as below`

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
       creationComplete="newCreationComplete(event)" fontSize="11" fontWeight="bold"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="News">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

        .messageStyle{
            height:20;
            fontSize:11;
            fontWeight:normal;
        }

    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            [Bindable] private var newsCollection:Array;

            protected function httpServiceNews_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {

                if(!newsCollection)
                    newsCollection = new Array();

                var atom:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
                var media:Namespace = new Namespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");

                var entryList:XMLList = (event.result as XML)..atom::entry;

                for each(var xml:XML in entryList){
                    var object:Object = new Object();
                    object.imageUrl = xml.atom::link..media::thumbnail.(@width == "106").@url;

                    object.summary = xml.atom::summary;
                    object.title = xml.atom::title;

                    newsCollection.push(object);

                }
            }

            protected function httpServiceNews_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            protected function newCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {

                httpServiceNews.send();

            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>

        <s:HTTPService id="httpServiceNews" result="httpServiceNews_resultHandler(event)"
                       fault="httpServiceNews_faultHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x" 
                       url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/hindi/index.xml" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:List  dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(newsCollection)}"  width="100%" height="100%"
             click="newsListSelectedIndexChanged(event)" >
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer 
                                    iconFunction="newsIconFunction"

                                    messageField="summary"
                                    labelFunction="myLabelFunction"
                                    messageStyleName="messageStyle">
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[

                            protected function myLabelFunction(item:Object):String{
                                return item.title;
                            }
                            protected function newsIconFunction(item:Object):String{
                                return item.imageUrl;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                </s:IconItemRenderer> 
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the default android font doesn't support this character set

You're going to want to embed a font with these characters in your app. This process is pretty straight forward, check out this link:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c6a9f451212b87fe7e87-8000.html

Comment: As the link suggests, I can only use TextArea or TextInput but I am currently using IconItemRenderer which uses StyleableTextField and doesn't work for that scenario. Do I have to create my own renderer?